Keeping shards of Chuppah Glass?
I was recently in a Judaica store and saw they have keepsakes for the glass that is broken under the chuppah. It also explains why the cups they sell come in many different unique colors (so they can make a nice decoration after).
I am wondering, is there any source for keeping the shards? And specifically to have them in some kind of decoration?
Or on the contrary, any reason to believe that one should not keep them or have them on display?
I also heard some communities give them out to people looking for a shiduch - any sources for this?
Thank you.

You could also get an urn to collect the ashes from under the chuppa

There is an observation by Shalom Sabar that the custom is pre-Christian German custom. https://youtu.be/Gpbhtq10qlY?si=uII9D5mW5oWGifob

Similarly, there are couples that keep the shards from the plate broken at the tenaim (could be glued back together).  It sounds like a nostalgic keepsake more than an ancient custom.

The source is the store that can sell you something additional if you do keep these pieces

If it provides an ongoing reminder of the hurban, there are worse newly invented customs
